# google play store aplication updates

Tags: java, android, google-play

You uploaded an APK that is not signed with the upload certificate. You must use the same certificate. The upload certificate has fingerprint:

```
[ SHA1: C0:04:E7:18:3C:17:84:22:70:BE:F8:38:8D:84:D6:F4:FE:BE:38:C3 ]
```

and the certificate used to sign the APK you uploaded have fingerprint:

```
[ SHA1: 88:0C:FF:07:7D:06:D2:20:8C:5C:AE:A2:43:C9:40:C5:BB:51:9E:2E ]
```

I Am trying to update my application in play store and when i check both V1 and V2 signatures as per the recent requirement, thats what am getting. What should i do please?

Answer (score 0):

As the message says, you are trying to upload an apk that was signed with a different Keystore that the one used for the original upload. Sign the apk with the same Keystore so that you can upload successfully